# Diff between STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT and STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT

Tags: php, stream

Hi I am new to php, i know to difference between STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT and STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT flag in Stream_Socket_Client().

Answer (score 0):

I see info STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT indicates that each subsequent connection should be opened without waiting for the completion of the previous one. (non-english src)